# Pointers for Linq in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

Hi all i wonder if someone can help, i've been given a piece of sql that i need to convert to Linq. However i'm quite new to using Linq and i'm unsure on how to do inner joins and things like that. I wonder if someone can point me in the correct direction? I'm using asp.net 4, specially using MVC.

Here is the sql:-

```
select 
acc.Account + ': ' + acc.TITLE as Description
from m_account acc inner join
(d_accountuserfields auf inner join m_userfields uf on auf.USERFIELD_ID = uf.ID)
on acc.ID = auf.ACCOUNT_ID
where acc.ledger = 'CONTRACTS'
and uf.TITLE = 'Customer Number'
```

Comment: Which LINQ provider are you using?

Comment: have you tried to write a normal SQL syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this collection of samples to be a useful reference (101 LINQ Samples): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

LINQPad can help you work through your queries and actually show you the generated SQL. If you're going to be working with LINQ a lot, you need this tool in your belt.
http://www.linqpad.net/